# Make drop down list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a window for device filters (as in the photo_1). This window contains all the elements of the 'Select a brand', 'Select a OS', 'Presence' lists at once.

But the more elements in these lists, the larger my device filter window gets.
I'd like to initially hide the list items, and make them a dropdown list (like in the photo_2).

Below is the part of the code that is responsible for displaying the list. How can I modify this code to add a drop down list?

```
  .......
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      title: const Text('Filters'),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      children: [
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            const Text('Select a brand'),
            ...brands.map((el) =>
                CustomCheckboxTile(
                  value: filters['brand']?.contains(el) ?? false,
                  label: el,
                  onChange:(check) => _handleCheckFilter(check, 'brand', el),
                ),
            ).toList(),
       .......
```

[image]

2nd Image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own customdropdown. A general example  Try as follows:

```
bool isClicked=false;

Column(children: [
      InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              isClicked = !isClicked;
            });
          },
          child: Row(children: [
            Text("Select".toString()),
            isClicked
                ? Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_down)
                : Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up)
          ])),
      !isClicked
          ? Container()
          : ...brands.map((el) =>
            CustomCheckboxTile(
              value: filters['brand']?.contains(el) ?? false,
              label: el,
              onChange:(check) => _handleCheckFilter(check, 'brand', el),
            ),
        ).toList(),
```

Comment: What should I put in instead of list1?

Comment: list1 is the list of items. For you it is the brands

Comment: I like your idea. But my list is not getting drop down. Please write how to insert your code into mine.

Comment: edited answer have a look

Comment: Strangely. I have an error :The element type 'List<CustomCheckboxTile>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this error?